# Apache Camel https4 client not using the same tcp port for multiple requests with keepAlive=true

Tags: https, apache-camel, keep-alive

Hi I am using Apache camel **http4 component** to send a **https** request with `keepAlive=true` but when i see the `netstat` after sending multiple requests I see each request opens a new **TCP port** to the peer.
I feel this should not be the usual behavior of **keepAlive transactions**, why the same TCP port is not being **reused** for communicating with the server and how can that be achieved if at all it can be.

Comment: Add some code showing how you have configured `keepAlive`, because in current docs there is no `keepAlive=true` option for HTTP4 component.

Comment: I use a http4 component and then call the url using the http4 component with keepAlive=true as a request header.Below is the code. <bean id="https4rtti" class="org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpComponent" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
  <property name="sslContextParameters" ref="sslContextParameters" />
  <property name="connectionsPerRoute" value="${perseus.connectionsPerRoute}" />
  <property name="maxTotalConnections" value="${perseus.maxTotalConnections}" />
 </bean>                                                https4rtti://someHostName/res?keepAlive=true

Comment: when i check the netstat for the destination address i see every time a new tcp port connection is being established of which after few seconds status changes to CLOSE_WAIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is not a keep alive problem; connections are in fact kept alive properly. The problem is that the connections as part of the pool managed by default PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager were not being reused. Both things could've been easily seen by enabling the logging for Apache's HttpClient (that's used under the hood):

Keep-Alive is being used:

2018/12/19 07:59:17:470 CET [DEBUG] wire - http-outgoing-7 << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
2018/12/19 07:59:17:470 CET [DEBUG] wire - http-outgoing-7 << "Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=300[\r][\n]"
2018/12/19 07:59:17:470 CET [DEBUG] wire - http-outgoing-7 << "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1[\r][\n]"
2018/12/19 07:59:17:470 CET [DEBUG] wire - http-outgoing-7 << "Content-Encoding: gzip[\r][\n]"
2018/12/19 07:59:17:470 CET [DEBUG] wire - http-outgoing-7 << "Vary: Accept-Encoding[\r][\n]"
2018/12/19 07:59:17:470 CET [DEBUG] wire - http-outgoing-7 << "Cluster-Id: A[\r][\n]"
2018/12/19 07:59:17:470 CET [DEBUG] wire - http-outgoing-7 << "Date: Wed, 19 Dec 2018 06:59:17 GMT[\r][\n]"
2018/12/19 07:59:17:470 CET [DEBUG] wire - http-outgoing-7 << "Content-Type: text/xml[\r][\n]"
2018/12/19 07:59:17:471 CET [DEBUG] wire - http-outgoing-7 << "Content-Length: 239[\r][\n]"
2018/12/19 07:59:17:471 CET [DEBUG] wire - http-outgoing-7 << "[\r][\n]"
Connections not being reused:

2018/12/19 08:00:08:240 CET [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://someurl.com:443][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 1; total allocated: 1 of 1]
2018/12/19 08:00:08:240 CET [DEBUG] DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-7: Close connection
2018/12/19 08:00:08:242 CET [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 8][route: {s}->https://someurl.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 1; total allocated: 1 of 1]
Note that one can easily enable logging for HttpClient by passing some arguments to JVM at startup.

So, why are connections not being reused then? This is due to the fact that SSL is being used and the PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager used by Apache's HttpClient not allowing reuse of a connection in case the user principal from the existing connection differs from the requested connection (facilitated by DefaultUserTokenHandler). See also e.g. this Stackoverflow post. Solution is to implement a custom UserTokenHandler (or use the NullTokenHandler if that's sufficient) and configure the HttpClientBuilder accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already analyze the **HTTP response headers** in order to check whether KeepAlive is being taken into account and with which timeout value.

Example of expected response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=20
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: ...
Content-Length: ...
```

Comment: content-type application/xml
connection keep-alive
content-length 258
#status# HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Comment: Yes the response headers i have checked and is given above. They contain the keep-Alive